# Page not found (404) jquery django python

Tags: python, jquery, django, static

не загружается jquery - Page not found (404)

**base.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="{% static 'bootstrap-5.0.0/css/bootstrap.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
  </head>
```

**setting.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ServiceCRM3/static'),]
```

- папка static создана
- скрипт лежит в пути static/jquery/jquery.js
- bootstrap подхватывает нормально в той же папке
- сервер перезапускал

что не так?

Answer (score 0):

```py
# urls.py (Главный)

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
...
...
...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
# После всех URL'оф добавляем путь к статике, иначе работать не будет
```

Подробнее можно почитать тут
https://djangodoc.ru/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development